# Getting error while sending an email with yashop-ses in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, amazon-ses

I used yashop-ses to send an email with amazon, for that i used this extension
https://github.com/ofat/yashop-ses , while using this extension i am getting error like `Undefined property: yashop\ses\libs\SimpleEmailServiceRequest::$resource`, here is my code

```
'mail' => [
            'class' => 'yashop\ses\Mailer',
            'access_key' => '*******',
            'secret_key' => '*******',
            'host' => 'us-east-1'
        ],

Yii::$app->mail->compose('contact/html') 
    ->setFrom('test@test.com')
    ->setTo('test@test.com')
    ->setSubject('Testing')
    ->send();
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: facing same issue .. anyone have any kind of solutions than please share .

Answer (score 1):

`Yii::$app->mailer->getSES()->enableVerifyPeer(false);` - this code fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
'host' => 'email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
```